# Reusing activerecord scopes on has many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Say I have a few activerecord models in my rails 3.1 project that look like this:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bugs
end

class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :component
    belongs_to :project

    scope :open, where(:open => true)
    scope :closed, where(:open => false)
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bugs
    has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs, :conditions => ["bugs.open = ?", true]
end
```

**In Short:** I have a has_many through association (`components_with_bugs`) where I want to scope the "through" model. At present I'm doing this by duplicating the code for the scope.

Is there any way to define this has many through association (`components_with_bugs`) such that I can reuse the `Bug.open` scope on the through model, while still loading the components in a single database query? (I'm imagining something like `:conditions => Bug.open`)

Answer (score 3):

**Rails 4 answer**

Given you have:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bugs
end

class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component
  belongs_to :project

  scope :open,   ->{ where( open: true) }
  scope :closed, ->{ where( open: false) }
end
```

You have two possibilities:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bugs

  # you can use an explicitly named scope
  has_many :components_with_bugs, -> { merge( Bug.open ) }, through: :bugs, source: 'component'

  # or you can define an association extension method
  has_many :components, through: :bugs do
    def with_open_bugs
      merge( Bug.open )
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `projet.components_with_bugs` or `project.components.with_open_bugs` will fire the same sql query:

```
SELECT "components".* FROM "components"
INNER JOIN "bugs" ON "components"."id" = "bugs"."component_id"
WHERE "bugs"."project_id" = ? AND "bugs"."open" = 't'  [["project_id", 1]]
```

Which one is better to use depends on your application. But if you need to use many scopes on the same association, I guess [association extensions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+extensions) could be clearer.

The real magic is done with [merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) which allows you to, as the name says, merge conditions of another ActiveRecord::Relation. In this case, it is responsible for adding `AND "bugs"."open" = 't'` in the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

The http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html specifies

> **:conditions** Specify the conditions that the associated object must meet in order to be included as a WHERE SQL fragment, such as authorized = 1.

Hence you can do it as:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bugs
  has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs do
    def open
      where("bugs.open = ?", true)
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

You can't specify another model's scope as a condition. In your case, they way you have it implemented is right. You can implement it another way as

```
has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs # in this case, no need to use the relation.

def open_bugs
  self.bugs.openn # openn is the scope in bug. Don't use name 'open'. It's a private method of Array.
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's reusing the scope so much as moving it onto the association - I still need to use the original scope (in other places in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your scopes , write the default scope as:
**`default_scope where(:open => true)`** in your "through" model **Bug**.

`class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base`
      `belongs_to :component`
      `belongs_to :project`
      **`default_scope where(:open => true)`**
      `scope :open, where(:open => true)`
      `scope :closed, where(:open => false)`
`end`

And in the Project model remove **:conditions => ["bugs.open = ?", true]**

`class Project < ActiveRecord::Base`
      `has_many :bugs`
      `has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs`
`end`

I think the above will work for you.

Comment: That would work, but it's still not re-using the original scope. What's more, setting a default scope would have a lot of side effects (on every line of code that loads Bug models).

Comment: has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs do 
   Bug.open
end

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.

`has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs do`
      `Bug.open`
`end`

Comment: For me that performs the same sql query as `has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs` - I believe that passing a block is for defining extension methods?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like this ?

```
has_many :components_with_bugs, :through => :bugs, :conditions => Bug.open.where_values
```

I haven't tested it, just proposing an path for investigation